# Does a cryptocurrency wallet blockchain need to be fully synched before it can be mined?

Tags: mining, cryptocurrency

I have a mining pool that is going to take several days to synch the blockchain, I'm wondering if I can have miners mining on it before the blockchain synchs or if I have to wait before blocks will be generated.  I suspect that I do, but perhaps this lovely site will erase that suspicion entirely :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about bitcoin network or any private blockchain network?

Yes, you have to sync entire blockchain wallet.

As we know that mining is the process of adding transactions to the large distributed public ledger of existing transactions and cryptocurrency wallet blockchain remains in syncing process automatically.
Mining and syncing of blocks works simultaneously, can you please explain what you exactly want to achieve?